# advanced custom validator for template driven form with dynamic input

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cvomu?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts)

- killerString needs a number on first position
- string1 + string2 + killerstring need a combined length less than 15 (for e.g)
- I tried to "copy/ adapt" the `pattern` validator from angular sources.

How can I have a customValidator that a "dynamic data" information attached. There is no "hook" in input where I can attach my "dynamic data"

Do you have any suggestions?

---

With Syed's help I got close ... its very hacky and Im sure it does not work when you have multiple fields using my `customLength` validator:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cvomu-zjlht5

---

#### Update 2

I've found a [WORKING SOLUTION](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cvomu-mzfsxz) with help of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjsaaUNw4lk) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162255/angular2-custom-validator-using-old-data).

one thing that is still lacking:

- when string1 or string2 are "changed" this does not trigger validation in `killerInput`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated post, you need to listen for @Input changes in the directive. It can be done with `ngChanges` and `registerOnValidatorChange`, which will help you to register the callback function to call when the validator inputs change.

killerInput class can be set with a template variable, ngClass and some style:

**HTML**:

```
  <input matInput #myInput=ngModel [ngClass]="{'error-class': myInput.invalid}" ....">
```

**Directive**

```
.....

  private _onChange: () => void;

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void { this._onChange = fn; }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

    if ('customLength' in changes) {
      if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
    }
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.error-class{
  border: 2px solid  red
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cvomu-typwzu)

You can check [this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-how-to-implement-conditional-custom-validation-1ec14b0feb45) article.

Answer (score 1):

change the following lines and check

**input-error-state-matcher-example.ts**

from

```
const total_name = customLength.arr.join();

if (total_name.length > customLength.maxLength) {
```

to

```
const total_name = customLength.arr?customLength.arr.join(''):'';

if (total_name.length < customLength.maxLength) {
```

**input-error-state-matcher-example.html**

from

```
<input matInput placeholder="killerstring" [(ngModel)]="killerstring" name = "TDkillerstring" #TDkillerstring = "ngModel" required [pattern]="pat1" [customLength]="{arr: [string1, string2], maxLength: 15}">
```

to

```
<input matInput placeholder="killerstring" [(ngModel)]="killerstring" name = "TDkillerstring" #TDkillerstring = "ngModel" required [pattern]="pat1" [customLength]="{arr: [string1, string2, killerstring], maxLength: 15}">
```

now you will get the error, if the combination of 3 textbox character's length exceeds a length of 15.

I have updated my code in stackblitz. check here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cvomu-7jpviu

Comment: could you fork my stackblitz?

Comment: forked in stackblitz, try in your local

Comment: First of all thank you: But I cant get it to work : `killerstring: 1ccc` should not give an error. But it does...

Comment: what are your values for all 3 text boxes?

Comment: your stackblitz is similar to my second try. However it has the same problems. `1.` does not show valid on first change from invalid to valid. (check console for this.), `2.` uses a single global variable that will surely give sideeffects  when using the directive in multiple places.